# Getting Data from Kaa server without using Log Apender

Tags: iot, kaa

I am using Kaa client to pump data to Kaa server. 
I want to fetch this data in order to showcase on a client application. With the use of Log Appenders, I am able to do so.
However, is it possible to do the same without adding any external db? I read in Kaa documentation that by default, Kaa stores data to MySQL (MaraidB / PostGre). 
However, when I tried to access Mysql (which is part of Kaa Sandbox), I was unable to do so.
Can anyone tell how can we do this?

Comment: I'm not sure you will be able to access the databases in Kaa sandbox. Kaa supports REST log appenders also. If you have any REST APIs to which the clients can post data to, then you can configure this. Please see [here](http://kaaproject.github.io/kaa/docs/v0.10.0/Programming-guide/Key-platform-features/Data-collection/Rest-log-appender/). Also check other [existing log appenders](http://kaaproject.github.io/kaa/docs/v0.10.0/Programming-guide/Key-platform-features/Data-collection/#existing-log-appender-implementations) too

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, Kaa should be configured to append the gathered telemetry to some Log Appender (one can also create a Customer Log Appender with specific functionality if required) or even a set of Log Appenders - depending on the use case.

The easiest way is to configure one of the existing Log Appenders to log the data to e.g. Cassandra and then retrieve the data from there.

Should you need real time triggering of some actions depending on the data received from client(s), you would probably need to try developing a Custom Log Appender for that.

Answer (score 0):

We need to have a external Log appender in order to log the data. The internal database takes care of Schema, event class families, Client/server profile info, notification info logging.